# Missing 0 value when using SUM(CASE WHEN) in SQL

Tags: sql

I used the query below to show summary table of score of all matches. 
The table game had id, mdate, stadium, team1, team2.
The table goal has matchid, player name, teamid, gtime so it records every single goal.

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as score1,
  team2,
sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as score2
  FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate, team1, team2
ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

The reuslt of my query was missing 2 cases, in which both team score 0.

Please help advise if my syntax was okay.

Comment: What is the schema of your `goal` table?

Comment: As per the question "The table goal has player name, teamid" , How come you make join on `matchid = id`, Please share your DBMS.

Comment: Can you provide the result you are getting and result you want to see?

Comment: When both the team scores 0, are you using `null` to track the goal or the value 0 itself?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except the ones who are arguments to set functions. I.e. do you need to GROUP BY matchid?

Comment: Thank you all for the question. I have updated again with the detail columns on Goal and Game table and the example data of those 2 tables.

Comment: @tom: you are right, I have edited my question, id was the PK of the game, matchid was the FK of goal that refer to id in game table. When team scores 0, I use the value 0 to track the goal.

Comment: @jarlh: no I did not select matchid to show and do not need to group by it, but to order by it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a `LEFT JOIN` when there may be no rows in the `goal` table for a particular `game`, but you still want the `game` row to produce a result row:

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as score1,
  team2,
sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as score2
  FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate, team1, team2
ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

This will produce `NULL`s rather than `0`s when there are no `goal`s to count, but that can be fixed by wrapping the `SUM` expressions with a `COALESCE`, if it's important that the result be `0`.

Comment: If both the teams don't have any goal, will it account to score?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - I admit, I'm assuming a fair bit about the schema that the OP *ought* to have put in their question but a relatively sane structure is `game (id, mdate, team1, team2)` and `goal(matchid,teamid)`, and that's what my answer is based on.

Comment: Damien, thank you for your answer. It works correctly and returning 0 for the case team has no score during the match. So I am not sure I get your point on the COALESCE expression though